# Track the actions that led to a multi-level drop down menu to open

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

**Goal:**

Track all the actions required to reach a certain level in a multi-level dropdown.

**Example:**

A multi-level dropdown like https://s.bootsnipp.com/iframe/xr4GW which can be opened by hovering on it. Once a menu item is clicked on the dropdown, how can one figure out what hover actions led to that part of the menu being opened ?

In the above bootsnip demo, if the first link in level 3 is clicked on, I want to be able to say that:

- 3rd link in level 1
- --> 2nd link in level 2, resulted in being able to
- ----> click the 1st link in level 3

**Current direction:**

Currently I'm using `mouseover` and `click` events to see if I can some-how co-relate all the events together. But no luck as of yet.

---

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Try `focusin` event. And `focusout` to revert

Comment: Is this for analytics or some other use case?

Comment: @7-zete-7 thanks for your suggestion. But, focus events don't seem to work for this usecase. Example, in the above snippet, the focus event is only fired on the final click in level 3.

Comment: @charlietfl partly analytical. Partly for an experimental project I'm playing around with ;)

Comment: You can push event data into an array and when a final event occurs get what preceded it in the array. Likely to be  bit complicated I think since there are so many elements that can get hovered just for "a peek" before a click occurs. So really not sure what you would want to discard and when

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for your suggestion. That is exactly the approach I have been playing around with by tracking all the elements that were being hovered on using `mouseover` event before a a final `click` event occurs. But like you said, there are many unrelated elements being hovered over during the course of the action. While I can probably using some heuristics to make it work with most of the common dropdown libraries it would not be complete nor would it be elegant. Hence the stackoverflow question to see if anyone has any better ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

I copied the snippet and made the following edits:

- added a collectable array `path`, in which the selected elements of the path will be indicated
- added listening for `mouseover` and `mouseout` events for `.dropdown-submenu` elements
- added rendering of the `path` array to be able to observe its changes

```js
var path = []
$(".btn-group, .dropdown")
  .hover(
    function() {
      $('>.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
      $(this).addClass('open');
      path.push($(this).children('a').text().trim());
      renderDebug();
    },
    function() {
      $('>.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
      $(this).removeClass('open');
      path.pop();
      renderDebug();
    }
  );
$(".dropdown-submenu")
  .on("mouseover", function () {
    path.push($(this).children('a').text().trim());
    renderDebug();
  })
  .on("mouseout", function () {
    path.pop();
    renderDebug();
  });

const $debug = $("#debug");

function renderDebug () {
  $debug.text(JSON.stringify(path, null, 2));
}
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  content: ">";
  float: right;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="card my-3">
        <div class="card-header">
          Bootstrap 4 Multilevel Dropdown Hover
          <div class="options float-right">
            <a class="settings"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="collapse"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="reload"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="fullscreen"><i class=" fa fa-expand"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="">
                                    Dropdown
                                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">level 1</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">level 1</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                                            level 1
                                        </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="#">level 2</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                                    level 2
                                                </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">level 2</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">level 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<pre id="debug"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @7-zete-7. While this may work for this specific dropdown case, I'm trying to form a more generic approach that would work for many kinds of dropdowns at a page level.